# Calculating mean in python with np, receiving str attribute error

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to calculate the mean of data from a csvfile in python. When I put in code, it is returning an attribution error. This is my code:

```
import csv
import os

userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
csvfile = userhome + r'/Desktop/Week2Milestone.csv'
with open(csvfile, 'r') as data:
    for line in csv.DictReader(data):
        print(line)
    
import numpy as np
child_mean = np.mean(csvfile.childs)
```

This is the error I receive:

```
child_mean = np.mean(csvfile.childs)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'childs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually csvfile is the string of the path of the file not the file itself. I think you should use a csv_reader, iterate in a for each to get the values and then do the mean.
To give an idea:

​

```
​with​ ​open​(​x​) ​as​ ​file​: 
 ​        ​csv_reader​ ​=​ ​csv​.​reader​(​file​, ​ 
         delimiter​=​','​)

         for row in csv_reader:
              Row[column] #you are accessing to the cell
```

Comment: So change the way I am importing the file to python?

Comment: Yeah, because you are actually trying to do everything with its path (which it's a string)